# Using SQL Server Management Studio against Azure SQL Data Warehouse

Tags: azure-synapse

I am aware that I can use SSDT in VS to connect to Azure SQL DW, but if I try and use SSMS, I run into two issues

1. the "No Count" issue when opening a new query window
2. Tables are not displayed in the Object Explorer but Views are

Is there some update/fix that needs to be applied to SSMS in order to use it against an Azure SQL DW?

Comment: In the July 2016 update for SSMS, you get Azure SQL DW support. :)

Answer (score 4):

Azure SQL Data Warehouse currently doesn't support SSMS. We are working on supporting SSMS as quickly as possible. You can follow the tutorial for connecting to Azure SQL Data Warehouse at the link below:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-data-warehouse-get-started-connect-query/

Comment: Much easier to use SSDT. Install it, and then use the URL in the Azure Portal to make the connection.